# Управление настройками браузера с помощью расширения

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, расширения

Меня интересует, возможно ли с помощью расширения, написанного мной управлять настройками браузера. То есть возможно ли это без открытий страницы с настройками и изменением настроек, а как-то автономно через расширение менять настройки браузера. В частности я бы хотел отключать какие-то уже установленные расширения двигая ползунок в своём, а не по тысяче раз заходить в настройки и вручную их отключать. Помогите информацией пожалуйста, что читать и где искать.

Answer (score 1):

Расширения не имеют доступа к включению/отключению расширений. Это было бы не безопасно.

Comment: хмм, даже не знал, спасибо